# Как передать аргументы в функцию генерирования расположения файла?

Tags: python, django

Требуется для поля `ImageField` генерировать параметр `upload_to` на лету. Нагуглил, что для этого можно передать в качестве параметра функцию. Ну допустим, вот так:

```py
def get_photo_path(instance, filename):
    return 'something'

class Photo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=get_photo_path)
```

Как мне передать при этом в функцию свой аргумент, кроме тех, которые джанго передает самостоятельно? Например я хотел бы передать еще аргумент `prefix`.

**UPD**. Попробовал сделать замыкание, чтобы моя функция возвращала другую функцию. Но теперь не могу сделать миграции, т.к. при выполнении миграций джанго пытается найти в модуле, из которого импортируется функция, название внутренней функции.

```py
def get_photo_path(prefix):
    def _gen_path(instance, filename):
        return prefix + 'something'
    return _gen_path

class Photo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=get_photo_path('smthng'))
```

При попытке выполнить миграцию (функция `get_photo_path` импортируется из другого файла):

> Could not find function _gen_path in my_module.utils

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему через создание дочерней модели от `ImageField`:

```py
class CustomImageField(ImageField):
    def __init__(self, prefix='', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='', **kwargs):
        self.prefix = prefix
        super().__init__(upload_to=self.custom_upload_to, **kwargs)

    def custom_upload_to(self, instance, file_name):
        return self.prefix + 'something'


class Photo(models.Model):
    img = CustomImageField(prefix='my_prefix')
```